# Knockout custom component with data-bind text

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a custom component, let's call it `mycomp`, that accesses text it's passed in its template like this:

```
<p>
    <!-- ko template: { nodes: $componentTemplateNodes } --><!-- /ko -->
</p>
```

I use this component in another component and try to pass a text to it like this:

```
<mycomp data-bind='text: myProperty'></mycomp>
```

When I try to run this, I get

```
Unable to process binding "component: function(){return l}"
Message: Multiple bindings (text and component) are trying to control descendant bindings of the same element. You cannot use these bindings together on the same element.
```

Is there a way to fix the issue and do what I want to do, namely use a component in another component and pass it text via `data-bind='text: ...'`?

Answer (score 1):

"text" binding only makes sense when used with native dom elements (div, span, etc) or virtual elements as it's changes all the element content with the specified text.

This is what the error message is saying (both, "text binding" and the component itself are trying to change the content).

Your component seems to output all the template nodes, so I think it will work if you do this:

```
<mycomp>hello</mycomp>
```

---

After your update, I think you have 2 options:

```
<mycomp>
    <!-- ko text: myProperty --><!-- /ko -->
</mycomp>
```

Or create custom parameter for your component, so you can do this:

```
<mycomp params="text: myProperty"></mycomp>
```

Details on how to to this are here => https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html

In your case, I think it would be like this:

```
ko.components.register('mycomp', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        this.text= params.text;
    },
    template:
        '<p data-bind="text: text"></p>'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, maybe my example wasn't the best... I'm trying to put a property of the viewModel into the text binding, not just `"hello"`... Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Thank you very much! Only the solution with `params` works; I think when doing it with `ko text`, the other component using `ko template` has a different `this` and therefore cannot access the property passed in `ko text`. Thanks again!